# Destructure complex object

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I'm trying to destruct a complex object, but I get no output in my console. I can't see why. I always get some sort of `Uncaught SyntaxError` in the browser. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. (EDIT: I'M ONLY TRYING TO LOG THE "HITS" TO THE BROWSER CONSOLE, NOT ACTUALLY PRINT THEM IN THE BROWSER) Here is the code:

```js
let catalog = {
  "artists": [
    {
      name: "Journey",
      "hits": [
        "Faithfully",
        "Only the Young",
        "Dont Stop Believing"
      ],
      name: "REO Speedwagon",
      hits: [
        "Keep On Loving You",
        "Time for Me to Fly",
        "Cant Fight This Feeling"
      ],
      name: "Styx",
      hits: [
        "Come Sail Away",
        "Mr. Roboto",
        "Blue Collar Man"
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let { hits } = catalog.artists;

for (x in hits) {
  console.log(hits[x]);
};
```

Comment: This is a simple case of mismatched curly braces. If you cleaned up the formatting you'll see this. Try copying your code into here and seeing what it looks like: https://beautifier.io/

Comment: right now you have a single artist, and are overwriting the name and hits each time.  You need at add a `},{` after each `hits:`

Comment: Not valid JSON.

Comment: as far as i know to destruct you need to use [] not {}

Comment: You can’t destructure a property by name from an array. Instead map over the array and destructure then.

Comment: I've read through a couple answers to your question, and a lot of them start with "If I understand your question correctly". Please clarify what output your're looking for. Are you looking to have an array or 'hits' logged to console?

Comment: sorry for the all caps on the edit lol

Answer (score 0):

This code has "some" more problems then just the " chars on the first hits which are way too much :) I think he wants to have a array of objects with the artist and the hits of the artists. BTW the album, tracklen etc. are missing dude ! ;)

```
            let catalog = {
            "artists": [{
                name: "Journey",
                hits: ["Faithfully", "Only the Young", "Dont Stop Believing"],
            }, {
                name: "REO Speedwagon",
                hits: ["Keep On Loving You", "Time for Me to Fly", "Cant Fight This Feeling"]
            }, {
                name: "Styx",
                hits: ["Come Sail Away", "Mr. Roboto", "Blue Collar Man"]

            }]
        };
```

and here our music lover was way to lazy. Otherwise he would have recognizce all the mistakes above :)

```
        for (var i = 0; i < catalog.artists.length; i++) {
          var hits = catalog.artists[i];
          console.log(hits.name);
          for (var j = 0; j < catalog.artists[i].hits.length; j++) {
            console.log("               "+catalog.artists[i].hits[j]);
          }

        }
```

will result in:

```
Journey 
          Faithfully
          Only the Young
          Dont Stop Believing
REO Speedwagon
           Keep On Loving You
           Time for Me to Fly
           Cant Fight This Feeling
Styx
           Come Sail Away
           Mr. Roboto
           Blue Collar Man
```

Not all the times every shortcut is needed, fast or even a great idea to show how cool you are.In this case it mixed you up cause you can not see any step in between while debugging.
At least the music taste isnt that bad :) Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. "hits" isn't nested directly under artists. "hits" is in an array of artists objects. I would just use an Array.map() to get the "hits" array off the "catalog.artists" array.

```js
var catalog = {
  artists: [{
      name: "Journey",
      hits: [
        "Faithfully",
        "Only the Young",
        "Dont Stop Believing"
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "REO Speedwagon",
      hits: [
        "Keep On Loving You",
        "Time for Me to Fly",
        "Cant Fight This Feeling"
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "Styx",
      hits: [
        "Come Sail Away",
        "Mr. Roboto",
        "Blue Collar Man"
      ]
    },
  ]
};

var hits = catalog.artists.map(x => x.hits);

console.log(hits);
```